Creating index on fileld from JSONB-column
I saw the following statement:
    CREATE INDEX orders_params_idx ON orders (((params ->> 'isInternal')::boolean))
         WHERE (params ->> 'isInternal') IS NOT NULL

Why do we need those WHERE IS NOT NULL part?
I would like to add separate index for another number type property - priority. Do I need to create another index with another name for it and for which type I have to cast it (::number, int4...)?
  CREATE INDEX orders_params_priority_idx ON orders (((params ->> 'priority')::number))
         WHERE (params ->> 'priority') IS NOT NULL


Are you sure you want to create an index on a boolean? And why do you want to create these indexes? Are there any queries that benefit from these indexes? If so, share the current query plans, using explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for these statements and the DDL for the tables and indexes involved.

It is hard to explain random bits of code you throw at us without any context.  The WHERE clause is apparently just there to make the index smaller by excluding the NULL values from it.  It actually makes the planner's work harder, and inhibits use of the index in certain circumstances.
